# C++ multiple instances of static variable in template function

Tags: c++, qt, templates, static

I have a curious issue I'd like to understand.

Consider the following function:

```
template<SomeEnumClass E>
static auto* getToolInstance()
{
    static Tool<E> instance;
    return &instance;
}
```

I'm also using a reflection util that builds an "if table" at compile time and may therefore use a runtime enum value as a template parameter.

The end result is something like this:

```
template<typename Functor>
static decltype(auto) UseEnum(SomeEnumClass E)
{
    if(E == SomeEnumClass::First)
    {
        return Functor::Action<SomeEnumClass::First>();
    }
    ...
}
```

Now the Functor in this case is this:

```
struct Functor
{
    template<SomeEnumClass E>
    static auto* Action()
    {
        return getToolInstance<E>();
    }
};
```

The issue:

```
getToolInstance<SomeEnumValue>() != UseEnum<Functor>(SomeEnumValue)
```

---

The setup that DOES work:

```
struct Functor
{
    template<SomeEnumClass E>
    static ToolBase* Action()
    {
        static Tool<E> instance;
        return &instance;
    }
};

template<SomeEnumClass E>
static auto* getToolInstance()
{
    return static_cast<Tool<E>*>(Functor::Action<E>());
}
```

I'm at a loss here.

EDIT:
This is somehow related to threading, possibly Qt. Everything works in a normal scenario, but it doesn't when the code is executed in an eventFilter.

Comment: MCVE please; work as expected [Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ba27d70eee193dea) (some change to make the code compilable).

Comment: I can't reproduce this outside the project. This can be called outside the main thread. Could this be the issue?

Comment: @Jarod42 What I can add is, during getToolInstance<SomeEnumValue>(), it enters _Init_thread_header from thread_safe_statics.cpp. CRT at fault?

Comment: Looks like it's related to Qt, see my edit.

Comment: While the issue may be related to threading I would doubt very much that it's `Qt` specific.  Of course you could prove me wrong by providing a [mcve] :-)